# Make Rails table column attribute read only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the best way to make my table column read only? disable the setter method? The column is set by postgres trigger, so I don't want to set it in the application level

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you look for ActiveRecord::Base [`attr_readonly`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_readonly/class):

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_readonly :bar
end

foo = Foo.create(bar: "first_value")
foo.bar
=> "first_value"
foo.update(bar: "second_value") #column `bar` ignored in SQL query
foo.bar
=> "first_value"
```

Comment: What if I want to prevent setting the column value while create as well? Basically I am creating a customer counter cache column which is updated manually based on some conditions.